# chartjs plugin datalabels does not show value on charts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, plugins, chart.js

I'm trying to get the values on each bar with the chartjs datalabels plugin.
So above the bar 'a' a want to see the number 30 and above or inside bar 'b' I want to see the number 50.

But it isn't showing any values at all.

Can anyone help and tell me what's wrong?

I've also tried to use different versions of chartjs but it didn't help.

Currently I'm using Chartjs 3.2.0
and for the chartjs-plugin-datalabels 2.0.0

here is an example in codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-js-plugin-5ez9p?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration) you still need to register the plugin before you can use it:

```js
import {Chart} from 'chart.js';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
```

Working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-js-plugin-forked-dig8k?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot! Actually I tried that and saw that in the documentation, but I might have done it wrong several times. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to register the chartjs-plugin-datalabels [plugin](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration).

For Registration you can also add plugins props to your TsChart.

1. import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
2. In TsChart tag add plugins props which accepts

```
Chart.PluginServiceRegistrationOptions[]
 
Eg. **TsChart type="bar" data={data} options={options} plugins={[ChartDataLabels]}**
```