# chartjs-plugin-datalabels not showing on stacked horizontal bar

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to make a simple horizontal stacked bar chart and add labels to it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, any input would be appreciated.

I can make it work by downgrading to a much lower version of chart.js and the datalabel plugin.

Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/chrispret/szLgyu2j/24/

And some test code...

```
const testData = {
    set1: '4',
    set2: '3',
    set3: '1',
    set4: '3',
  };

const data = {
  labels: ["test"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'set1',
      data: [testData.set1],
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'center',
        align: 'center',
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'set2',
      data: [testData.set2],
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'center',
        align: 'center',
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'set3',
      data: [testData.set3],
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'center',
        align: 'center',
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'set4',
      data: [testData.set4],
      backgroundColor: 'gray',
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'center',
        align: 'center',
      }
    }
  ]
};

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        aspectRatio: 15 / 3,
        indexAxis: 'y',
      elements: {
        bar: {
          borderWidth: 2,
        }
      },
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        x: {
          stacked: true,
        },
        y: {
          stacked: true
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          color: 'white',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          },
          formatter: Math.round
        },
        legend: {
          position: 'right',
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Chart.js Horizontal Bar Chart'
        },
      }
    },
  };

  const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chartDemo'),
    config
  );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chartjs plugin datalabels does not show value on charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818360/chartjs-plugin-datalabels-does-not-show-value-on-charts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 1.x, the `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` plugin no longer registers itself automatically. It must be manually registered either globally or locally as described [here](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration).

Therefore, to make it work, you could add the following line to your code prior to create the chart.

```
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
```

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
const testData = {
  set1: '4',
  set2: '3',
  set3: '1',
  set4: '3',
};

const data = {
  labels: ["test"],
  datasets: [{
      label: 'set1',
      data: [testData.set1],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    {
      label: 'set2',
      data: [testData.set2],
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },
    {
      label: 'set3',
      data: [testData.set3],
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'center',
        align: 'center'
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'set4',
      data: [testData.set4],
      backgroundColor: 'gray'
    }
  ]
};

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    aspectRatio: 15 / 3,
    indexAxis: 'y',
    elements: {
      bar: {
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'center',
        align: 'center',
        color: 'white',        
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        },
        formatter: Math.round
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'right'
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Horizontal Bar Chart'
      },
    }
  },
};

Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('chartDemo'),
  config
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartDemo"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perfect, after adding the line to register datalabels, it is working. Such a simple thing I overlooked there.

Answer (score -2):

Add the labels to the labels array.

```
  const data = {
  labels:  ["hrZone1","hrZone2","hrZone3","hrZone4"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'peak',
      data: [hrData.peak,0,0,0],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    {
      label: 'cardio',
      data: [0,hrData.cardio,0,0],
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },
    {
      label: 'fatBurn',
      data: [0,0,hrData.fatBurn,0],
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    },
    {
      label: 'under',
      data: [0,0,0,hrData.under],
      backgroundColor: 'gray'
    }
  ]
};
```

[image]

Comment: All that does is to create several series with those labels. I want a label with the value in the middle of each piece of the bar. See here (https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/bar.html), but with only one bar.

Comment: you might need to set your dataset arrays. Check updated answer :)

Comment: Your updated answer still is not a stacked bar and there are also the datalabels plugin is still not working since it still doesnt show any labels